# Recursive routine escape for backtracking routine

Tags: python, recursion

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this recursive routine for a sudoku back-tracking problem. I was wanting to get out of the recursive routine when the a certain problem had been executing for a known quantity of time, in this case - 2 seconds. However, I am having some trouble getting this to work and believe there may be something wrong with my base case. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def solver(Domains,SudokuSolv):
    start = time.time()
    global global_length
    global global_row_index
    global global_column_index
    global global_val_index
    global global_number

    if global_length == 0:
        return True
    else:
        global_row_index+=3
        global_column_index+=3
        global_val_index+=3
        print(global_row_index)
        row = Domains[global_row_index]
        col = Domains[global_column_index] 
        val = global_val_index

    for i in Domains[val]:
        end = time.time()
        if end-start > 2:
            global_length = 0

        Checker = isValid(i,row,col,SudokuSolv)

        if Checker == False:
            SudokuSolv[row][col] = i
            print(SudokuSolv)
            global_length-= 1
            if solver(Domains, SudokuSolv):
                return True
            global_length+=1
            SudokuSolv[row][col] = 0
        else:
            print("Trying next value...")

    global_row_index-=3
    global_column_index-=3
    global_val_index-=3
    return False
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest reading about [mre]. You'll be much more likely to get an answer if you follow the advice there.

Comment: Local variables are local to each recursion call, so you can't measure the total time difference using the local variable ‘start’